# Mediastore.Audio.Media.DATA return nothing

Tags: android

I tried to list all audio file with a Cursor and Content resolver, I get song title, artist of songs and Id but the problem is that I can't get the path it return nothing when I try to display it in Toast.

Thanks for your help.

Here is the code and how I get songs:

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = this.getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI; 
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"); 



    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int pathColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            String thisPath = musicCursor.getString(pathColumn);
            arrayChansons.add(new Chanson(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisPath));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        musicCursor.close();
```

Comment: Where did you see documentation saying that the column indicated by  `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` would contain the file path? (You may be right, I'm just trying to get at the details.)

Comment: I saw it on this forum and on this link too: http://www.androidcookbook.info/android-media/mediastore-for-audio.html

Comment: It's said here: "int fileColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex (MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

The first one is the index of the column containing the path to the actual audio file. We got the foregoing index by passing in the constant that represents that column, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA "

Comment: Specify what columns you want, rather than passing in `null` for the columns, and see if that helps.

Comment: I've specified column that I want but nothing changed.